# Convert LambdaExpression to typed Func<T,TOut> and invoke it

Tags: c#, .net

I have expression class to store config and actions to apply mapping:

```cs
public class ExcelMemberConfigurationExpression<TDestination, TMember> {
  public List<LambdaExpression> Actions { get; private set; } = new List<LambdaExpression>();

  public ExcelMemberConfigurationExpression<TDestination, TMember> UseAction(Func<string, TMember> action)
  {
    Expression<Func<string, TMember>> expr = (member) => action(member);
    Actions.Add(expr);
    return this;
  }
}
```

I want to convert `LambdaExpression` back to `Func<string, TMember>` and `Invoke` it in Map method:

```cs
foreach (var action in actions)
{
   var newVal = action.Body.As<Func<string, object>>().Invoke(value);                
}
```

but I receive error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.InvocationExpression1' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression'1[System.Func`2[System.String,System.Object]]'.'

Comment: You have to compile the expression `expr.Compile()`

Comment: @HMZ I do this but get {Method = <Internal Error evaluating expression>}

Comment: Something like this should work: `action.Compile().Invoke(value)`.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes action.Compile().DynamicInvoke(value) works. thank you.

Comment: Why would you like to add the expression, instead of the function itself?